# How to change the keyboard-layout in the console, with special characters?

Tags: keyboard-layout, console, special-characters

I want to use the dvorak-fr-bepo keymap in the console (tty1 to 6) when I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>. In particular, I need the special characters as "Ê" or "ç" since there are some in my password.

So directly when I installed Ubuntu, I chose for the Bépo layout when asked.

Nonetheless, the consequence is that I am able to type basic characters, but not special ones. For instance, when I typed <kbd>B</kbd><kbd>É</kbd><kbd>P</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> I got only "bpo".
On the contrary, when I used to use a French Azerty layout, I could type the special characters.

How do I definitely set a different keyboard-layout in the console?

Comment: I suggest to begin removig `console-data`.

Comment: What is the output you got vs what you expect? Example do you got "ć" instead of "ç"?

Answer (score 2):

Install package `console-common`, then use commands `install-keymap` to install a default keymap from a `.kmap` file, or `loadkeys` to switch between layouts. Use `man` on these commands for more info.

Comment: `sudo loadkeys /usr/share/keymaps/...` so I chose some keymap from there

Comment: `# loadkeys fr` or whatever language, to switch keyboard layout on Ubuntu recovery mode root terminal