# Why do a lot of programs crash in segmentation fault?

Tags: virtualbox, skype, segmentation-fault, boinc

For a few days, a lot of programs do not launch properly. This includes Skype, Oracle VM Virtualbox, Scilab, Boinc, LÖVE, OMG! Words! and a little Java program I downloaded from the web (RemoteDroid). When I launch them from the terminal, I get the same error: `Segmentation fault`.

I cannot figure out which is the recent change I made on my computer that is the origin of those errors; is it because I changed my [keyboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60504/how-to-change-the-keyboard-layout-in-the-console-with-special-characters)-[layout](http://bepo.fr/wiki/Console_linux)? Or because I installed a lot of [programs for developers](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/09/series-introduction-ubuntu-development-part-2/)?

Notice that it is a general problem, not for just one only application. Moreover, since the two first are closed source, I will not be able to compile them.

Comment: [Segmentation faults](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) occur when a program crashes because some part of its code is buggy and tried accessing a memory location when it is not able to. If you see this occurring, you should file a bug for it, as these are programming errors that definitely need to be fixed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either you recently upgraded a library that the programs share to a new, buggy version, or you have developed a hardware problem, such as overheating.

Comment: What do you suggest? That I reinstall the whole OS? That I change my computer?

Comment: @Agmenor, make sure your computer isn't clogged with dust that could be making it overheat, and yes, a reinstall wouldn't hurt.  See if you still have problems without updating.

Comment: Reinstall of Ubuntu solved the problem.