# Can't Enter Password in Recovery Mode

Tags: command-line, login, recovery-mode

When I go into recovery mode to get to the command line, I enter "telinit 3" to drop out of root. This works on my desktop, but on my laptop it asks for my username and password, then I hit enter and the first letter of my password appears and it doesn't log me in. It then proceeds to ask me for my username and password again, and the issue continues. Am I doing something wrong? Is this a known issue with a solution?

EDIT: Worked around this by going into /etc/default/grub and setting it to boot in text mode. Still would like a solution for this though.

Comment: On your laptop, did you by chance set a root password ? If so, log in as root with the root password you set.

Comment: bodhi.zazen, it seems that the issue may be that the output of telinit is being entered into the original root console, though I'm not sure if this is the case. Also, in recovery mode you already start as root.

Comment: Do you have special characters in your password? Do you have a special keyboard layout? I had also a close problem: http://askubuntu.com/questions/60504/how-to-change-the-keyboard-layout-in-the-console-with-special-characters

Comment: Agmenor, no special characters and no special keyboard layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(OP solved problem)*

> Worked around this by going into /etc/default/grub and setting it to boot in text mode. Still would like a solution for this though.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu, you don't start `telinit 3` to work normally. Watch out for hints on starting up. AFAIK, if you have done as root what you needed to do, you just enter

```
exit
```

and then get asked how to proceed with a small menue of about 5 options.

Comment: I don't want to be running as root, but otherwise you are right.

Comment: In recovery mode, you start automatically with superuser rights.

Comment: I'm aware, but that isn't what I want. I want to log in as a user.

Comment: So you don't want to do any recovering at all - you just want an text-based login screen and session without X11?